# How to prevent url navigation to administrative pages on website

Tags: php, html

I want to create a logout / sign out link from a 'members only' area of my website. So I created a `logout.php` script for this that the sign out link will navigate to and then I used header to redirect to `index.php`. My question is how do you prevent an user from navigating to the `logout.php` script by simply typing in the URL?

How do you prevent this for any instance for that matter?

For clarification:

I want users to logout using the sign out link ONLY i.e. by clicking on it; not by typing in the URL address of the logout script.

`logout.php` is as follows:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    unset($_SESSION);
    session_destroy();
    header ('location: index.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: Generally, that is accomplished using cookies and server-side validation of them in your PHP script or in the HTTP server.

Comment: [Tutorial: 
Basic Login Authentication with PHP and MySQL](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Basic-Login-Authentication-with-PHP-and-MySQL.html)

Comment: I'm not sure I get you. I did unset session and destroy it. This is part of the logout.php script. This still doesn't prevent a logged in user from navigating to the logout.php by typing in the url.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to prevent a user typing in a URL?

Comment: If typing a URL in the nav bar somehow defeats security at your site, the problem is not in the nav bar.

Comment: Well I'm trying to prevent access to administrative pages, e.g logout.php.

Comment: logout.php should be a public page, why would you want to stop users from logging out?

Comment: Sorry if the initial question was unclear. I want users to logout using the sign out link ONLY i.e. by clicking on it; not by typing in the url address of the logout script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop that by making the logout.php a POST page rather than normal GET. One way of doing this is changing your Log Out link to actually be submitting a form, rather than just a normal link. Then on the logout page, check the form was really submitted before logging out. That will mean anyone just typing in the URL won't be logged out, while users clicking the link will be.

An example of this would be to make your HTML like

```
<form action="logout.php" method="post" name="logoutform">
<input type="hidden" name="logout" value="y">
<a href="javascript:document.forms['logoutform'].submit()">Log Out</a>
</form>
```

You'd probably want extra CSS to remove the form styling too.

The code in logout.php can be:

```
<?php
if ($_POST["logout"] == "y") {
    /* Getting here means they clicked the link, so log them out */

}

?>
```

You can't stop them from typing logout.php in the browser, but this will ensure they will only actually log out when they submit the form (i.e. click the log out link). Just typing in the URL will get a blank page.

Comment: Yeah that would definitely work. I was hoping that I wouldn't have to resort to a submit button though. Haha. Thanks.

Comment: I think it's most reliable way to ensure they only logout when they intend to. Even stackoverflow works this way - try clicking http://stackoverflow.com/users/logout  ;)

Comment: Hmm, yeah that's interesting!

Comment: They blogged about why it's this way too, it's interesting reading: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/09/cross-site-request-forgeries-and-you.html

Answer (score 0):

> I want users to logout using the sign out link ONLY; not by typing in the url address of the logout script.

It is not really possible to avoid a visitor from changing the address bar URL in *their* browser. There's no real way to determine how the user accessed `logout.php` -- by typing in the URL directly or from a page on your website.

I think you're approaching the issue from the wrong perspective, but if you *really* want to do this, I'd suggest using a [session variable](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).

Comment: Appreciate your help. I am using session variables. here is the logout.php script: <?php
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])){
 unset($_SESSION)
 session_destroy();
 header ('location: index.php');
}

?>

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic logout in PHP.

```
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
     <li>
       <i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i><input type="submit" name="cerrar" value='Cerrar sesión' style="outline:none;padding: 0; border: none; background: none;">
   <?php
      if (isset($_POST['cerrar'])) {
             session_start();
             session_unset();
             session_destroy();
             header("location: index.php");
             exit();
       }
   ?>                                            
    </li>
      </form>
```